# What is the best way to configure angular cli build watch mode and nodemon watch?

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack, angular-cli, nodemon

Hi I am developing a mean app using angular 4. I have used angular cli configuration. I want to auto build the code using watch mode and also want to restart the node server when any files changed.

I used the following command but not working

```
script: {
   "server": "ng build -w && nodemon --watch src/**/*.ts --exec ts-node ./bin/www"
}
```

I have kept the configuration in the directory `bin/www` file which is importing `server.ts` from other place.

The problem for above command is, ng cli is building the code with watch enabled but nodemon is not starting.

So i tried the following. but its building only one time as watch is not enabled for cli.

```
script: {
   "server": "ng build && nodemon --watch src/**/*.ts --exec ts-node ./bin/www"
}
```

> nodemon watch not working in either case.

Comment: Why not just use ng serve? It can act as a proxy to your node server if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah but i think that will run on two different ports. I want to use express server for both ui and api. Can i run both on a single command? Please help me if i am wrong.

Comment: ng serve can act as a proxy to your node server. So it serves angular resources directly, and proxies the API requests to your node server. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. I think this will work for me. I will try this and let you know. Thank for your support. :)

Comment: @JBNizet As per your solution its working but i need to start the nodemon separately. I used `concurrently` to run both angular build and nodemon simultaneously like below.

```
"nodemon": "nodemon --watch src --exec ts-node ./bin/www",
"server": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start\" \"npm run nodemon\"" 
 ```

 The problem here is nodemon is not restarting. I think its watching wrong path. See the following logs

 ```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: D:\Projects\mean-app\src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `ts-node ./bin/www`
 ```

Answer (score 7):

Based on the comments above this is how I made 2 servers working and responsive to any changes.

- create Angular 2 app using angular-cli tool, frontend server
- create server.js file in the root of this app, backend server, example of Express app is [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli)
- install package **npm-run-all** to start 2 servers simultaneously
- create file server.conf.json in the root of the app with the following content

> ```
> {
>   "/api": {
>     "target": "http://localhost:3000",
>     "secure": false
>   }
> }
> ```

- modify package.json to have this section

> ```
> "scripts": {
>   "client": "ng serve --proxy-config server.conf.json",
>   "server": "nodemon server.js",
>   "start": "npm-run-all -p client server"
> }
> ```

- run "npm start"

Now **ng serve** is watching any changes in Angular and **nodemon** - in Node.

```
localhost:4200                  // ng serve => angular
localhost:4200/page             // ng serve => angular
localhost:4200/another/page     // ng serve => angular
localhost:4200/api              // ng serve => node
localhost:4200/api/users        // ng serve => node
localhost:3000/api              // node
localhost:3000/api/users        // node
```

Comment: Yes! thank you. I really wanted to stay with ng serve and another solution for the server. also - clear explanation

Answer (score 1):

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server:run\" \"npm run server\" \"ng serve --aot --progress=false --proxy-config proxy.conf.json\"",
    "lint:client": "ng lint",
    "lint:server": "tslint './server/**/*.ts' -c ./server/tslint.json --fix",
    "test:client": "ng test --watch false",
    "e2e:client": "ng e2e",
    "build": "ng build --prod --sm=false --aot --output-path=dist && npm run server:build",
    "server:run": "nodemon",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "server:build": "tsc -p ./server",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "build:prod":"ng build --prod --sm=false --aot --output-path=dist"
  }
```

**proxy.conf.json**

```
 {
      "/api/*": { // need to change api with your specific name appropriate to your http 
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false
      }
    }
```

Then do **npm start** or **npm run start**

Comment: Works but im running npm run server:run because npm run server cause an error saying that the port is already in use.