# Mean Stack Application with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

Im making a MEAN stack application with Angular 4.

**What I've done:**

1. Created a MVC directory structure for my Node/Express App.
2. Created a Node/Express server.
3. Created a basic API which with express with a prefixed path of `/api`
4. Tested the API using POSTMAN
5. Used Angular-Cli to create a angular project within my root directory of the MEAN stack app.
6. Within `.angular-cli.json` changed `outDir` property to `../public`
7. Changed my Server file to send Send all other requests (that are not going to `/api`) to the Angular app

**My Directory Structure:**

[image]

1. **angular-src** folder contains the angular app generated by `angular-cli`
2. **app-api** folder contains my API which performs all CRUD operations. This is where all the `/api` routes are directed to.
3. **app-server** folder contains just a route file which sends all `/` to the angular app (`public/index.html`)
4. **public** folder is where the angular app's `index.html` file lives after running `ng build`
5. **app.js** is where my node/express server lives and redirects incoming api requests

**When I run the app it works. The node server sends my requests to the Angular Apps `index.html`  with the `public` folder and that displays my `app.component.html` template.**

---

**My questions:**

- I run `nodemon` to start my node/express server & then navigate to `angular-src` folder and run `ng build` to setup my angular app. This process seems quite lengthy to me whats a better way of achieving this?
- Also I have to run ng build every time I make changes to the angular
  app so it can read the changes. Is there anything like `nodemon` but
  for angular that watches for changes and resets automatically.
- I have 2 `package.json` files. Once for node/express and another for angular. Should there be only 1 `package.json` file within a project?
- The App finally has to be launched on **Heroku** currently I have a **Procfile** which contains `web: npm start`. How do I manage angular 4 within heroku? Do I need to add a `ng build` command to the Procfile?
- Should the Angular App & Node/express run different ports (i.e port 3000 & 4200) or should both be on a single port?
- Is the structure that I've implemented suitable for a MEAN App using Angular 4.

I know some of these questions might be opinion based but I'm looking for your professional advice as to whats considered **best practice** within these situations.

Comment: For development, you can use a `proxy.conf.json` file for port-forwarding and use `npm-run-all` as described in this answer to have it run with a single command - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743298/4365626

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two cents on that (I have an application running on Heroku too in production mode, I followed every Heroku tutorial and the most known ones) :

- You have to run `ng build` everytime. the build allows you to minify your code, while ng serve doesn't. I am not aware of how you can make it automatic, but if you're using Heroku, just pushing to your repo will build your project (if you use the right commands of course)
- Yes, you have to rebuild on every change. And if you i18n your app, you will have to run `ng build` for every language you implemented. So you shouldn't make it automatic, given the time it will take (for me, 2 languages = 6 minutes)
- I keep only one `package.json` where i put all my dependencies (back & front)
- my build commands for Heroku are as follows :

  ```
  "postinstall": "npm run build-i18n",
  "i18n": "ng xi18n --output-path src/i18n --out-file messages.xlf",
  "build-i18n:fr": "ng build --output-path=dist/fr --aot --prod --bh /fr/ --i18n-file=src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=fr",
  "build-i18n:en": "ng build --output-path=dist/en --aot --prod --bh /en/ --i18n-file=src/i18n/messages.en.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=en",
  "build-i18n": "mkdir dist && npm run build-i18n:en && npm run build-i18n:fr"
  ```

The `postinstall` is launched by Heroku, which launches both builds for both languages.

- You should have different ports. In fact, launching them on the same port is impossible.
- The structure of your project can be as you like. It's up to personal preference. But my recommendation is to follow John Papa's guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions. I just wanted a few clarifications. When I run `ng build` it seems like its running it on a single port (3000 in my case). How can I run them on different ports? Also can you point me towards a few good heroku tutorials? Again thanks.

Comment: ng build isn't using any ports. Ng build is building (duh) your project, by minifying your code, and putting it into vendor scripts. ng serve will use a port, nodemon will use one too, but ng build won't ! For the tutorials, I recommend you start here : [Deploy an angular app on heroku](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352)

Comment: thanks again mate. There just so many things to figure out its gets confusing.

Comment: I understand. Don't worry, it took me 2 weeks to have it done. But once you've done it, this is pretty much it, all you have to do left is code !