# Is there a way to run nodemon and ng serve?

Tags: node.js, angular, nodemon

I am hosting my angular application using a node server. Every time i do a change in angular, I need to run build command. I am using webpack for packaging and build. Is there a way to publish changes directly to node server using nodemon so it can work as ng serve does?

It may be a duplicate or absurd idea but will be helpful if I can gather the thoughts. Obviously this is only to make the local development & troubleshooting easy not for production instances.

Comment: I think this maybe can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743298/13335131

Comment: Thanks @KToxcon but my angular is served with node. If i run both servers separately, i ll have to update the node service URLS from relative (/project/api) to something like (localhost:3000/project/api). Which means i ll to change this again before development env code push.

Comment: `npm-run-all` seems to be the only answer to your question. If not, try elaborating the question for a more precise answer. Link to the package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all